# Meteor Set Meteor.settings.public

Tags: meteor

I am trying to set Meteor.settings.public as shown below in order to be able access public keys from my app client or server side, yet I am always getting error in Chrome - console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'public' of undefined
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong / missing here? Thanks

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
   var pubSecSettings = {
        BaseUrl : 'https://www.google.com',
        CompanyName : 'Test'
   };
   Meteor.settings.public = pubSecSettings;
 });
```

Note: The code above is placed under /server/config/global.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Meteor.settings` is a built-in feature - you don't need to write all that code in order for it to work. Take the following steps:

1. Remove the above code from your project
2. Add a file called settings.json in the root folder of your app. Here is an example:

```json
{
  "awsBucket": "my-example-bucket",
  "secretKey": "ABC123",
  "public": {
    "companyName": "Test Inc."
  }
}
```

3. Start your server with `meteor --settings settings.json`

Now the public keys (in the case `companyName`) we be available to the client via: `Meteor.settings.public`. The server will have access to all of the keys via: `Meteor.settings`.

I **strongly** recommend carefully reading [this post](http://joshowens.me/environment-settings-and-security-with-meteor-js/) on   security issues on this topic.

Comment: Thanks David, adding the file under the common folder returned the same error, but adding the check if null lines made it work smoothly. Having said so I noticed that I can access the public and non-public keys from the client side, even though as far as I understood from Meteor documentation "Except for .public all other properties of Meteor.settings are only defined on the server." so I was wondering what does it mean that those properties are only defined on the server? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you probably just wanted to use `Meteor.settings` in the default way. I rewrote the answer to give step-by-step instructions on how to use the feature.

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciate it